# Change image once document is ready using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change an image in my webpage once it is completely loaded using jquery. I'm trying to follow [this example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimpleSlideshow/) but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody help? What I'm trying now is below:

```
<div class="img1">
     <img src="images/nice.png" class="hideimg">
     <div class="area">
          <img src="images/wrong.png" class="showimg">
      </div>
</div>
 style
.hideimg{display:none}
.showimg{display:block}
onload jquery
   $("document").ready(function()
{
    $(".img1").attr("src",image).removeClass("hide_image").addClass("showimg");
});
```

Comment: Help me to animate between two image like this http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimpleSlideshow/   i need to alternatively change image after a particular interval

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
if ( $(".img1 img").hasClass("hide_image") ) {
    $(this).addCladd("show_image");
}
```

Comment: Help me to animate between two image like this css-tricks.com/examples/SimpleSlideshow i need to alternatively change image after a particular interval

Comment: You can use `setInterval` function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Download the cycle plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html

Check the below code html

```
<div id="s1" class="img1"> 
    <img src="images/nice.png" width="200" height="200" /> 
    <img src="images/wrong.png" width="200" height="200" /> 
</div>
```

style

```
.img1 {  
    height:  232px;  
    width:   232px;  
    padding: 0;  
    margin:  0;  
} 

.img1 img {  
    padding: 15px;  
    border:  1px solid #ccc;  
    background-color: #eee;  
    width:  200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    top:  0; 
    left: 0 
}
```

Write jquery like below

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
    $('#s1').cycle('fade');
});
```

Comment: Help me to animate between two image like this css-tricks.com/examples/SimpleSlideshow i need to alternatively change image after a particular interval

Comment: Check the above code, Use plugin to show the animation you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I understand you correctly, please let me know if I misunderstand you:

http://jsfiddle.net/HNQgJ/

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $(".hideimg").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hideimg").addClass("showimg");
    });
});
```

Just one thing, you seem to mess up with class names, you have to decide which one to use, I see you use both "show_image", "showimage", "showimg"...

Tim.

Comment: i need to animate alternate display of these two image